# VirtualBox Error after OSX Big Sur 11.4 upgrade

Tags: virtualbox, macos-big-sur

VirtualBox failed to initialize after an upgrade to OSX Big Sur 11.4

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine xxx.

The virtual machine 'xxx' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

The following step resolved the problem:

```
sudo csrutil clear
```

followed by a reboot

The reboot took a long time.

Note that I did not need to uninstall or reinstall VirtualBox, like [this related problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408154/macos-big-sur-virtualbox-error-the-virtual-machine-has-terminated-unexpectedly-d)